# Better Organzing ArrayLists from Txt files

Tags: java

In My program, I am reading a text file and making many arraylists (either 8 or 9 depending on what the user is looking for) that will be manipulated with to find averages, peaks and valleys.  The file is set up in the format:

ID  Contract  Date  Open  High  Low  Close  Volume
ID1 Contract1 Date1 Open1 High1 Low1 Close1 Volume1
... and so on

I seperate them into arraylists by doing this

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (scanDaily.hasNext())
    { //while
        double value = scanDaily.nextDouble();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
        df.format(value);
        list.add(value);
    }  //while

    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < list.size(); c1++)
    { //for
        counter1++;
        if (counter1 % rows ==1)
            ID.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows ==2)
            Contract.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 3)
            Date.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 4)
            Open.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 5)
            High.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 6)
            Low.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 7)
            Close.add(list.get(c1));
        else if (counter1 % rows == 8)
            Volume.add(list.get(c1));
```

Is there a more effective or efficient way of organizing this text file.  It gets VERY big and as I try to get more complicated with my math (like only using parts of the arraylists to find averages and such from certain time periods) I am having serious issues getting my code to work.

This answer doesn't have a right answer, I am just looking to see what the community of Stack Overflow has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use Object Oriented approach i.e. Create a class representing your file data and then store the objects of that class in a hashmap against the ID attribute. It will help you to organize your code to a great deal in terms of readability and simplicity.

This is how your record class should look like, I don't know the different attributes in your file so I have considered most of them as string. You can change the types as per your need:

```
class Record {

    String ID;

    String contract;

    Date date;

    String open;

    String high;

    String close;

    List<String> volumes;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getContract() {
        return contract;
    }

    public void setContract(String contract) {
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(String open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public String getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public void setHigh(String high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    public String getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(String close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public List<String> getVolumes() {
        return volumes;
    }

    public void setVolumes(List<String> volumes) {
        this.volumes = volumes;
    }


}
```

Define your map like this:

```
Map<String,Record> recordsMap = new HashMap<String,Record>();
```

Create Record instances with proper attribute values as read from each line and then store the Record against ID or other key as desired.

Comment: I was afraid of this.  I am terrible with Object Orientation stuff.  Oh well, guess its time to learn :-(

Comment: Why do you vary between Strings, Dates, and Lists.  I do no understand

Comment: @user2474459 I don't have much knowledge about the data in your file. I used used against a date1 considering it may be having some date data. I thought you have multiple volume information as Volume1 ... and so on. Class was created only to get you started on the right appraoch. Customize it to your real need.

Comment: I dont know what a map is.  Wow one semester of java is no where near enough for the real world, yikes.  How can I accept your answer??